# What is the purpose of using params attribute in GetMapping annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use spring boot 3

I don't understand the difference between both

```
@GetMapping(value="/{id}", params="name")
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonPayload>> findPerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam String name){
   ...
}

@GetMapping(value="/{id}", params="name")
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonPayload>> findPerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam("name") String name){
   ...
}
```

The use of params attribute in getMapping, is it the same thing then using a requestParam?

Comment: It allows further narrowing of mapping based upon a parameters value. Answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73292194/642680

Answer (score 3):

From the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#params--) that is an alias for [RequestMapping.params()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--)

> The parameters of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.

> Same format for any environment: a sequence of "myParam=myValue" style expressions, **with a request only mapped if each such parameter is found to have the given value.** Expressions can be negated by using the "!=" operator, as in "myParam!=myValue". "myParam" style expressions are also supported, **with such parameters having to be present in the request (allowed to have any value).** Finally, "!myParam" style expressions indicate that the specified parameter is not supposed to be present in the request.

For example, let's say we have method annotated with `GetMappings` and specified with `params`

```
@GetMapping(value="/{id}", params="name")
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonPayload>> findPerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam String name){
 ...

}
```

Then the `GET` request having `name` as query param will be mapped to the method `findPerson`

```
GET - http://localhost:8080/1?name=robert
```

If the request param `name` is not present then below error will be thrown

```
GET - http://localhost:8080/1

Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "name" not met for actual request parameters:
```

The value provided in @RequestParam("name") is to bind query parameter with `name` value to variable

```
@GetMapping(value="/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonPayload>> findPerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam("name") String name){
 ...
}
```

One other advantage is we can follow java naming convention for variable incase query parameter having any symbols or `_`

```
@GetMapping(value="/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonPayload>> findPerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam("first_name") String firstName){
 ...
}
```